# FitClient: external process terminated before a connection could be established.

Tags: fitnesse

I am creating Sample Fitnesse Test and facing this error while running test

fit

Date:   6:34:29 PM (IST) on Tuesday, April 9, 2013

Test Page:  .CalculatorRunner

Command:    java -cp fitnesse.jar; fit.FitServer devcode 8082 12

Exit code:  -1

Time elapsed:   1.013 seconds

Standard Error:
 Error: Could not find or load main class fit.FitServer

Internal Exception:
 FitClient: external process terminated before a connection could be established.

### code at C# side

```
   namespace ConsoleApplication1
   {

   public class CalculatorRunner : ColumnFixture
    {

       int arg1;

       public int Arg1
       {
            get { return arg1; }
            set { arg1 = value; }
       }
       int arg2;

       public int Arg2
      {
           get { return arg2; }
           set { arg2 = value; }
      }


      public int Sum()
      {
           return Arg1 + Arg2;
     }
   }
}
```

### And Code for Fitnesse Page

```
 !path C:\..\bin\Debug\*.*



!| import |
| ConsoleApplication1 |

!1 Let's run a simple calculator
!| CalculatorRunner |
| Arg1 | Arg2 | Sum? |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

For C# fixtures you need a different fit server:

http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/UsingFitnesse.html